# extracting <table> from html with sed magic

Tags: unix, sed

I have an html page with many tables.

```
<html>
<table>
  POINTER_TEXT
  some other stuff
  <table that i want START>
  </table that i want END>
  some other stuff
  <table bad>
  </table bad>
</table>
</html>
```

I wish to grab a table that comes after a specific text. I am good until this stage.

```
curl -silent http://xyz.com/1.htm | sed -n '/POINTER_TEXT/,$p'
```

This gives me

```
  POINTER_TEXT
  some other stuff
  <table that i want START>
  </table that i want END>
  some other stuff
  <table bad>
  </table bad>
</table>
</html>
```

Then I add this:

```
curl -silent http://xyz.com/1.htm | sed -n '/POINTER_TEXT/,$p' | sed -n '/<table*/,/<\/table>/p'
```

which gives me this:

```
  <table that i want START>
  </table that i want END>
  <table bad>
  </table bad>
```

My problem is I just need this:

```
  <table that i want START>
  </table that i want END>
```

Help me please guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
| sed '\=</table={p;Q}'
```

at the end. This should throw away everything after the first table end.

**But**, what will your script do if there are no newlines in the html? It is far more robust to use a real *parser* to process HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the guide you will need: [click](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html)

> (1) The general solution is to use GNU sed or ssed, with one of these
>   range expressions. The first script ("print only the first match")
>   works with any version of sed:
>
> ```
>  sed -n '/RE/{p;q;}' file       # print only the first match
>  sed '0,/RE/{//d;}' file        # delete only the first match
>  sed '0,/RE/s//to_that/' file   # change only the first match
> ```

Comment: gives me this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `/'

Comment: can you give me the first one with my requirement? Whats RE?

Comment: sorry I went ahead with the other answer, but this one would have been much concise. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/POINTER_TEXT/,${/<table/,/<\/table/{/<\/table/!b;q}};d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do you might fare better with a real parser as *choroba* suggested. Conveniently, W3C already [provides](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) one which accepts [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Example input "infile":

```
<html>
<table>
  POINTER_TEXT
  some other stuff
  <table>
  Wanted data
  </table>
  some other stuff
  <table>
  Not wanted
  </table>
</table>
</html>
```

In order to extract the first `<table>` descendant of `<table>`, use `hxselect` like this:

```
hxselect 'table > table:first-child' < infile
```